# Return first row of multidimensional array

Tags: arrays, codeigniter, multidimensional-array

I have this value inside my database which is inserted using multiple upload.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [user_id] => 1
            [image_id] => 1
            [title] => testing
            [image_name] => 59435c5f0838f.jpg
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [user_id] => 1
            [image_id] => 1
            [title] => testing
            [image_name] => 58435c5f0838f.jpg
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [user_id] => 1
            [image_id] => 2
            [title] => testing
            [image_name] => 57435c5f0838f.jpg
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [user_id] => 1
            [image_id] => 2
            [title] => testing
            [image_name] => 56435c5f0838f.jpg
        )
)
```

For some reason I want to display only **first or one row** of image of each `image_id`. For example refer to array `[image_id] => 1` have **2 different images** and `[image_id] => 2` also have **2 different images**, but I want to return `[image_id] => 1` only **1 image** and `[image_id] => 2` only **1 image**

My model function selecting from database

```
public function loadAll(){
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('tbluser');
    $this->db->where('user_id', $this->getUserId());
    $query = $this->db->get();
    $row = $query->result_array();
    if($row != null){
        return $row;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: are you using mysql database??

Comment: @AsifRahaman yes I am

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a Group By statement if you are using mysql database.

```
$query = $this->db->select('*')
          ->from('tbluser')
          ->where('user_id', $this->getUserId())
          ->group_by('image_id')  /* Add this group by statement */
          ->get();
```